# IOException on RandomAccessFile's readBytes function during file monitoring

Tags: java, file-io, ioexception

I am monitoring a log file of another java process that is constantly writing to it. These two processes (monitoring application and the monitored application) is running on the linux distro, centos.

The problem is that everytime I restart the monitored application, the monitoring application seem to get this error:

> java.io.IOException: Input/output error
>     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
>     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:361)
>     at LogMonster.fileChanged(LogMonitor.java:57)
>     at FileMonitor.fireFileChangeEvent(FileMonitor.java:96)
>     at FileMonitor$FileMonitorTask.run(FileMonitor.java:128)
>     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
>     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

I keep a Map with file name as key and RandomAccessFile object as value and I populate it as follows after adding this object as a listener:

> monitor.addFileChangeListener(logMonitor, LogFileName, LogMonitor_Properties.getTimeDelay());
>      randomAccessFile_list.put(LogFileName, new RandomAccessFile(LogFileName, "r"));

An event is fired every time the file is modified and it is within the eventFired function that I'm trying to read contents from the RandomAccessFile after the monitored application was restarted (before it is restarted it works fine).

The following line of code within the 'fileChanged' function is causing the error:

> randomAccessFile_list.get(file.getAbsolutePath()).read(byteArray);

I use a bash script to kill all versions of the application and then restart it in a 'go' file.

Contents of go:

> cd /path/to/app
>
> ./kill
>
> nohup ./app.run &

Contents of kill:

> kill -9 $(lsof app.run| awk '{print $2}')
>
> kill -9 $(lsof app.log| awk '{print $2}')
>
> kill -9 $(lsof app.go| awk '{print $2}')

Contents of app.run:

> ./app.go >>app.log 2>&1

Contents of app.log:
 Just text output of the application.

Contents of app.go:

> . /path/to/some/other/location/setClassPath.go
>
> export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH
>
> echo $CLASSPATH
>
> /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH MyApp

I apologise for posting a question that looks exhausting before you've even read it, but I'm really at my wits end and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code relevant to the line number where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the method names it appears you're using [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-enterprise-authzserver/source/browse/trunk/projects/authzserver/source/java/com/google/enterprise/util/FileMonitor.java?spec=svn153&r=153) for file monitoring. It actually isn't opening the file, it's just stat'ing it every once in a while.

You're then also keeping a separate file handle open to the file in your map.

The library fires an event only when the modified time changes - this doesn't mean there's any new *data* added to the file. You then apparently attempt to read from your filehandle and get an IO exception.

There's a number of issues with this approach, but without seeing more of your code it would be impossible to tell you exactly what the problem is. I'm guessing that the monitored process is truncating, deleting, or doing something else with the file when it restarts that is invalidating your open filehandle.

File monitoring like this is generally used when you want to reload the entire file (usually a properties file, or a document being edited), not for trying to do a "tail".

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me. I ended up going with [apache commons' Tailer class](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) and it worked out fine, however it does take up a little more system resources but still not enough to be worried about it.